# What is the Explicit Formula for $\log(\zeta(s))$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, mellin-transform

The explicit formula for the logarithmic derivative $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is illustrated in (1) below.

---

**(1)** $\quad\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{s}{1-s}+\log(2\,\pi)-\frac{1}{2}H_{\frac{s}{2}}+s\sum\limits_\rho\frac{1}{\rho\,\left(s-\rho\right)}$

---

**Question (1)**: Is there a analogous explicit formula for $\log(\zeta(s))$?

Comment: It is $\sum_\rho \frac{1}{s-\rho}+\frac1\rho$ not $\sum_\rho \frac{1}{s-\rho}$ (a consequence of the density of zeros, itself a consequence of the functional equation). The series converges absolutely and locally uniformly so you can integrate it $\int_{s_0}^s$ without fear. Of course there is the problem of the branches.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but can't you use: $\zeta(s)=\prod_{p} (1-p^{-s})^{-1} \implies \ln(\zeta(s))=-\sum_{p}\ln(1-p^{-s}) $

Comment: @Mason explicit formula means series over the zeros, not over the primes. Your sum (with the correct branch of $\log$) converges only for $\Re(s) > 1$ and assuming the RH can only be regularized for $\Re(s) > 1/2$.

Comment: @reuns I copied the wrong formula, so I replaced formula (1) above. I was investigating integration of the formula and having trouble with the branches which led to this question.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a curve $a \to b$ then $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{s-\rho} ds = \log(b-\rho)-\log(a-\rho)+2i\pi k$ and finding the correct $k=k_{\rho,\gamma}$ (equivalently the correct branch) is a problem treated in every text on complex analysis. The possible $k_{\rho,\gamma}$ is constrained by the fact the series must converge, so overall you have an uncertainty $\log \zeta(s)+2i\pi K$ with $K$ finite and depending on your path of integration. Usually we start with $\log \zeta(s)$ analytic for $\Re(s) > 1$ then we fix $K$ from the path of integration from $\Re(s) > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

use this works find
$$\log (\zeta (x))=\Re\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \log \left(1-\frac{x}{\rho _k}\right)-\text{log$\Gamma $}\left(\frac{x}{2}+1\right)-\log (x-1)+\frac{1}{2} x \log (\pi )+\log \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: At best your formula could only converge for $x>1$. I was looking for a globally convergent formula for $\log\zeta(s)$ (for all $s\in\mathbb{C}$).